Ugreen KVM switch burned my HDMI cable. Is this common with KVM switches?
I have a PC with 2x GPU, 2x monitors, 2x HDMI cables. Yesterday I have purchased a KVM switch “KVM Ugreen CM664 HDMI switch”, I have never had such a device, and when I first used it, I was amazed how well it fits my needs. My happiness did not last long though, as soon the second monitor went black. While restarting the KVM device, I noticed there is a power supply port - indeed, the device requires power, supposedly only for USB (it’s HDMI+USB switch), but I thought hey, maybe that’s why monitor went black, maybe device doesn’t have enough power. I connected the power, and was able to use the device for a bit - I thought all is well, until the second monitor, yet again, went black. Long story short, after much debugging (2x GPU/monitor/hdmi +/- kvm, I had lots of combinations to go through), it looks like my HDMI cable is burned - it doesn’t work anymore - I have that cable for 1 month, it was working just fine, it’s also a very expensive one (it’s 10m cable so I bought the best one available to not have issues), and now after adding kvm to the mix, suddenly the cable is not working…
I mean, I am very confused - I never though a CABLE can get burned? Now I am wondering - I of course will return the cable under warranty, I think I will also return the KVM as it scares me - but the functionality offered by a KVM in general, is something that I need. Is this behavior common? I.e. - if I purchase a different KVM, do you think there is a real chance of something like this happening again?

This is the wrong website for this question, but my advice is to test the cable by connecting your monitor directly to your computer, both with the cable you're testing and another cable you know works. If it still isn't working, return it to the shop that sold it to you. I think it's unlikely that a KVM switch destroyed your cable, more likely the cable broke by coincidence

I've had two ugreen products (two different models of Ugreen USB-A to USB-C cables in this case) literally catch fire. I have the same cables (I usually buy in multiples) that have not exploded into flames - my conclusion, quality control at ugreen is lacking.
